# Spartan II XC2S50 TQG144 ASM 13 - decoupling capacitor values

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

I have a damaged board out of a CCD camera that requires replacement of the Spartan II FPGA chip (XC2S50 TQG144 ASM 13) and a few decoupling ceramic caps around its periphery. There is no schematic or BOM available for the board.

The caps are 1608 (measured with callipers) but the Spartan datasheet makes no specific mention of values. I'm guessing, around 0.1uf but I am not sure how critical the application is. It's low voltage. 1.5 - 3.3v according to the [data sheet.](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xilinx.com%2Fsupport%2Fdocumentation%2Fdata_sheets%2Fds001.pdf)

How critical are the cap values?

Answer (score 1):

Usually not very, give 100nF or so a try, it will probably be fine.

Xilinx do actually usually publish decoupling recommendations for their parts, but they are almost always very much worst case and generally somewhat overkill even for prototypes.